# Why does clang 4.0 not catch std exceptions?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have the following sample code that throws a `std::ios_base::failure` and tries to catch it, using clang 4.0 in c++11 mode:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int
main()
{
  try {
    throw new std::ios_base::failure( "Bonkers" );
  }
  catch( std::ios_base::failure &e ) {
    std::cout << "Failure " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch( ... ) {
    std::cout << "Anything" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I compile the program like this:

```
clang++-4.0 --std=c++11 -g -W -Wall ex.cc -o ex
```

And I get the output:

```
Anything
```

I would have expected for it to catch the specific exception. I tried the same with g++ 5.4, but the same result. Also tried without the c++11 flag, does not help either. Taking out the catch all clause gives me this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]*'
```

So what am I missing, and what can I do to fix this? The abi:cxx11 is also shown when I am NOT using the c++11 flag.

Comment: You are throwing a `std::ios_base::failure *` and trying to catch a `std::ios_base::failure`. Those are not the same type.

Comment: Change `throw new std::ios_base::failure( "Bonkers" );` to `throw std::ios_base::failure( "Bonkers" );`

Comment: You meant `throw std::ios_base::failure( "Bonkers" );`

Comment: I think this is worth keeping open.  While it is a simple type error; it doesn't seem to be a typographical error.  This seems like a common mistake, especially for people coming to C++ from languages like Java.  Therefore I'd expect lots of future SO users to find this useful.

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks, I have spent the last three years in Javaland, and recently came back to C++. So if anyone would like to formulate an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in C++ you do not need to allocate the exception via new and hence throw the pointer to the exception, as would be done in Java.

Instead you simply construct the exception and throw it:

```
throw std::ios_base::failure( "Bonkers" );
```

Then the types of the catch clause will match, and the program will behave as expected.